# Best way to use multiple accounts on Bitbucket from my laptop

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I have 2 Bitbucket accounts:

- https://bitbucket.org/myaccount1/
- https://bitbucket.org/myaccount2/

I added all SSH keys necessary on these 2 accounts (all is ok about this).

In my config file (under ~/.ssh directory):

```
Host bitbucket.org - myaccount1
  User git
  Hostname bitbucket.org
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myaccount1

Host bitbucket.org - myaccount2
  User git
  Hostname bitbucket.org
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myaccount2
```

But, I can't access (authentification error) to myaccount2 from my Git client. For myaccount1 it's perfect, it works.

If I want to access to myaccount2 I must to delete all informations about myaccount1 in the config file. And I have just now in this file:

```
Host bitbucket.org - myaccount2
  User git
  Hostname bitbucket.org
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myaccount2
```

Like that, it's ok now, I can access to myaccount2 without any problem.

How can I configure this config file properly to keep my access on these 2 accounts ?

Thank you very much guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config file has the same name in both `Host`: "bitbucket.org".

You need to give a different name to each one, and then adjust your git remote url accordingly.
For example:

```
Host bitbucket.org
  User git
  Hostname bitbucket.org
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myaccount1

Host othername
  User git
  Hostname bitbucket.org
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myaccount2
```

And then:

```
git clone git@othername/whatever.git
```

will clone from `myaccount2`

More information [here](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/)

Comment: Thank you very much ! The official link I just saw: https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=271943168#ConfiguremultipleSSHidentitiesforGitBash,MacOSX,&Linux-CreateaSSHconfigfile